# To check if there is a common substring in 2 strings c++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, find, substring

I've already made a solution, but I need an optimised solution. The task is to:

1. Read two strings
2. Get every substring of the 1st string and find each of them in the second
3. If it exists, print "yes" or else print "no"

The solution I've already made:

```
int check(string A, string B)
{ 
    string s3;
    int flag=0 ,len1,len2,k=0;
    s3[0]='\0';
    cin>>A>>B;
    len1=A.length();
    len2=B.length();

    for(int i=0;i<len1;i++)
    {
        k=len1-i;

        for(int j=1;j<k;j++ )
        {
            s3=A.substr(i,j);

            size_t found=B.find(s3);

            if(found!=string::npos)
            { 
                flag=1;
                return flag;
            }

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: While pasting a code here, please keep/make the formatting(indentation) proper, so the code would be readable.

Comment: what minimal common substring  length required? we may say that one common character is common somestring

Comment: Have you tried searching for "longest common substring problem"?

Comment: If there is no length limit for the substring, then you could just print yes always, because the empty string is a common substring of all string pairs.

Comment: There is no need to check all possible substrings (which are O(n^2)), since if a substring is common to both strings, then all its substrings are also common (even the single characters).  Therefore, it's sufficient to just check for common characters.

Comment: You should post your code to [Code Review StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I ll see to tat @MehrdadMomeny !

Comment: @AlanStokes i ll i ll check dat !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all characters of the first string into a hash set (unordered_set), then iterate on characters of second string and check if any of them exist in the hash set. If so, then there exists a common substring (of length 1 at least) otherwise, there is no common substring.

Comment: (In an environment where getting the length of a string is cheap, use the shorter string to populate the set.)

Comment: Dats a better solution! Thanks!! a map is an optimised solution .. o(1) : for insertion and search!!

Comment: @sindhuja Actually, it's o(log(n)), not o(1)

Comment: @V.Kravchenko okay !! 
   
     `  int check(string A, string B)
  return B.find_first_of(A) != std::string::npos;       `                                                                                                          Is this an **optimised** code or the one with maps ?

Comment: @sindhuja Map search and insertion is o(log(n)), but not o(1).

Answer (score 1):

```
bool check(const std::string & a, const std::string & b) {
   return b.find_first_of(a) != std::string::npos;
}
```

You see, if string `b` doesn't contain a substring with size 1 from `a` it just can't contain a larger substring beginning with the same symbol. So you just basically need to check if string `b` contains any symbol from string `a`.

Comment: You can replace most of this with a single call to [`std::string::find_first_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of)

Comment: Thanks!! this worked with my code with lesser time!! wat is the complexity of find_first_of(a) ?

Comment: Map still makes a optimised solution rite ?

Comment: @sindhuja Depends heavily on `std::string::find_first_of` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has other issues besides optimized solution.
For eg not all code paths return a value.

The most efficient solution depends on number of factors including the size of the two strings, how much the two strings match etc.

In absence of these information I propose that you could either use:

1. Create a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) from the second string
2. Create a [suffix array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) from the first string
3. Generate all substrings of 2nd string using suffix array. Along with generation check for its existence in the trie created in step 1.

Other approaches that you can consider includes modifying [rabin karp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) which shouldn't be very hard to figure out.

Comment: Please give me examples for which my code fails..But to check if 2 strings hav a common substring.. i need nt generate all substrings rite?

Comment: Get **every** substring of the 1st string and find **each** of them in the second.
In your question you mention **each** and **every** which means all substring.

Comment: ok !! dats wat i ve done in my program!! i got all substrings and checked! but that takes too much of time ! To find common substrings i jus hav to check if the 1st character of the second string is in te 1st !                              Thank you for the idea of trie ... will check it out  !!